# Execute function while mouse is at certain position

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, scroll, mouseevent

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
var mouseY = //mouse y-position relative tot some element

while (mouseY > 0 && mouseY < 200){
    //scroll element -5px
}
```

I want to scroll a certain element up as long as the mouse is within a certain area of an element.

Getting the mouse position and scrolling is not the problem (using [scrollTo plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html)),

I just can't figure out how to bind this to an event and keep it repeating whil the mouse is in the required area...

Hope someone can point me in the right direction...

Answer (score 1):

After doing the scrolling, set a timer to re-check the mouse state again in, say, 50 milliseconds.

[`window.setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout)

Comment: `setTimeout(your_callback_here, 50);`